Space Complexity of Merge Sort
What is the specific space complexity of the Merge Sort algorithm, as partially implemented below?
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    ...

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    // Create temp arrays
    int L[n1], R[n2];
    ...

I think the space complexity at any level of recursion is the auxiliary space of merge + recursion stack of mergeSort, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of calculating the space complexity.

Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question about this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions here and here and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about.

I removed my answer and moved it to the answer section, is this better?

I think your assessment of the space used in merge as annotated in the diagram (in rev. 4/self-answer) incorrect:
I see r-l+$O(1)$.
In particular, merging two parts of length 1 uses two arrays of lenght 1, no matter the length of arr/$n$ - unless you assume fully parallelised (which I'd consider purely academic).

When each part has length 1, nothing happens. Merging happens for parts of length 2 or bigger. In worst case, all merge functions in any level of recursion run in parallel, and their auxiliary space becomes O(n).  Is this correct?

So for ordering an array of 3 million values you afford, say, 1.5 million processors?

I just realized my mistake and probably your point. So we're either at the first level of recursion and the merge auxiliary space is O(n), or we're at log(n) level (with recursion stack auxiliary space being log(n)) and the merge auxiliary space is O(1).

Update: Below answer is WRONG. I keep this post so that you can understand the context of other answers.
Below is my solution to the problem and I'm not sure if it's correct, I've put it here so other's can vote or comment.
The auxiliary space complexity of the merge function is n+5, which is freed when merge function exits.
The auxiliary space complexity of sort function appears to be 2*S(n/2) + 1, where the additional 1 accounts for the midpoint variable.
In the k-th iteration, the equation becomes 2^k * S(n/2^k) + (2^k - 1).
If we let n=2^k, the above equation simplifies to n * S(1) + (n-1). Since S(1)=0, the equation reduces to n-1.
Total space complexity, in the final depth of recursion, should be O(n) (for the input) + n-1 (for the recursively stacked m variables in previous mergeSort calls) + n+5 (for the temporary variables in the merge function).
I'm unsure about this analysis, as it's a homework assignment. Could anyone please confirm?
UPDATE:
For example, consider merge sorting an array of size 8.

Note that the auxiliary space of each merge is n+5, but for simplicity, I've represented it as n in the recursion tree diagram.
As shown, at any level of recursion (k), the auxiliary space is equal to the merge auxiliary space + the auxiliary space of the recursion stack at that level.
Therefore:
Auxiliary Space = n + 2^k-1
n=2^k => Auxiliary Space = n + n-1 = 2n-1
n=8, k=3 => Auxiliary Space = 8 + 7-1 = 2*8-1 = 15
The overall space complexity (assuming input space complexity is n for simplicity) is:
Space Complexity = input space complexity + auxiliary space
Space Complexity = n + 2n = 3n = O(n)

As written, you need n items of extra space to sort n items.
You can instead design the algorithm so that merging a sorted copy of the first n/2 elements and the sorted but not copied second n/2 elements works within the array, reducing the extra space to n/2 items.

The management of recursion alone indeed costs $O(\log(n))$ as the recursion depth is $\lg(n)$ and a call takes stack frames of constant size.
Now, taking into account that the function Merge releases its working memory after having performed the merge, only $n$ extra elements are needed.
